# Is it ok to ask about another SO question without copying its code?

Tags: discussion, minimal-reproducible-example

I'm looking at:

[The output of function overloading is not as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465759/the-output-of-function-overloading-is-not-as-expected?noredirect=1#comment93803014_53465759)

This is a question about another SO question (which in turn is about overloading in C++). The newer question regards a point not covered in the earlier question, but which could have (or perhaps should have) been covered. However, the new question does not quote the context, and the code, listed in the first question.

Should the new question considered to be lacking an MCVE, or lacking content in general? Or - is it enough to link to another SO question and ask something supplementary?

Comment: It is such a basic question, every half-decent C++ programmer knows the answer.  It is never going to be a top Google hit.  Heck, it is never going to be found again now that Google doesn't index our content anymore.  So what could possibly be the point of closing as "unclear what you are asking" when it is crystal clear?  Of piling on downvotes when one is enough to roomba it?  Of 14 useless comments when it only takes one to help the guy out?  Just don't help if you don't want to help.  I took care of it.

Answer (score 9):

Questions and answers should be self contained, no matter what.

Even Q&A from Stack Overflow could be closed and deleted, and can't be considered *stable* for published viewing.

Thus links are serving as a *decoration* at best.